Macro to delete blank cells in row
I have a macro to delete blank cells in each row and shift the next cell to the left. The code is not showing any errors, but does nothing.
As the number of columns can vary from row to row, I have defined the last row inside the For Each loop.
Help with correction gratefully received.
Sub RemoveBlankCells()

Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ABC")

For Each row In ws.Rows
    lastCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rng = ws.Cells(1, lastCol)
  For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If cell.Value = "" Then
        cell.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    End If
  Next cell
Next row

End Sub


ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count) will always look at row 1 and ws.Cells(1, lastCol) will always look at just the last cell on row 1.  Your For Each will always look at all rows - no matter how many are populated with data, so it will run across all 1,048,576 rows even if there's only data in row 1.

This one might help , change r.Clear to r.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft, and maybe some more adaptions, because it's looking for formulas, not empty cells though.

Thanks @DarrenBartrup-Cook - also explains the poor performance. Do you have a recommendation instead of For Each?

Thanks @Excellor - unfortunately not with ws.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) - had tried UsedRange before without success.

Try this code. It limits it to just populated rows - assuming column A always has something in it.
Public Sub RemoveBlankCells()
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ABC")
    
        'Assume there's always something in column 1.
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        
        'Set reference to column A of the range to work on.
        Dim SearchRange As Range
        Set SearchRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 1))
        
        Dim rRow As Range
        For Each rRow In SearchRange.EntireRow
            
            'Find the last column number in the row.
            Dim LastColumn As Long
            LastColumn = .Cells(rRow.row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            
            'Work backwards deleting cells - if you delete a cell in column 3 and move to column 4...
            'column 4 has now become column 3 and that cell isn't checked.
            Dim Counter As Long
            For Counter = LastColumn To 1 Step -1
                If .Cells(rRow.row, Counter) = "" Then .Cells(rRow.row, Counter).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            Next Counter
        Next rRow
        
    End With

End Sub  

Further reading:
With...End With statement

Thanks again @Darren Bartrup-Cook - It seems to go directly from If .Cells(rRow.row, Counter) = "" Then to Next Counter, i.e. skips .Cells(rRow.row, Counter).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Are you sure those cells are empty and don't contain a space?  Add Debug.Print .Cells(rRow.Row, Counter).Address & ": " & Len(.Cells(rRow.Row, Counter)) before the IF line - it will print the cell address and number of characters (length) in the cell.

Thank you - that was it!  Spaces in the cells! Thank you so much - you have saved me much frustration!

You could update the check in the IF statement to Trim(.Cells(rRow.Row, Counter)) to remove any leading or trailing spaces.

I have added a trim to fix the issue with spaces:        Dim cell As Range         For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)         cell = WorksheetFunction.Trim(cell)         Next cell

Try also this compact piece of code. It is fast, not needing iteration:
Sub testDeletEBlankCellsSlideLeft()
  Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  On Error Resume Next 'for the case of no any blank cells in sheet used range...
   rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlToLeft
  On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Edit
This version is even more compact, not needing On Error Resume Next:
Private Sub testDeletEBlankCellsSlideLeft_()
  With ActiveSheet
    If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.UsedRange) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete xlToLeft
  End With
End Sub


This code uses the ActiveSheet.UsedRange. Collects all empty cells and then remove and shift left the remained.
Sub delete_cells()
Dim todel As Range, cel as Range   '*
For Each cel In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  If Len(cel) = 0 Then
    If todel Is Nothing Then
    Set todel = cel
    Else
    Set todel = Union(todel, cel)
    End If
  End If
Next cel

If Not todel is Nothing Then todel.Delete xlToLeft '*
End Sub

* as of VBasic2008 commented

Improve with Dim todel As Range, cel As Range & If Not todel Is Nothing Then todel.Delete xlShiftToLeft.

Remove Row Blanks

Main
Sub RemoveBlankCells()

    Dim rg As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ABC").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Set rg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1) ' exclude headers
    End With
    
    RemoveRowBlanks rg
    
End Sub

Help
Sub RemoveRowBlanks(ByVal rg As Range)
    
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim RowsCount As Long: RowsCount = rg.Rows.Count
    Dim ColumnsCount As Long: ColumnsCount = rg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim Data() As Variant:
    
    If RowsCount + ColumnsCount = 2 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
    Else
        Data = rg.Value
    End If
    
    Dim Row As Long, sCol As Long, dCol As Long, IsNotSameColumn As Boolean
    
    For Row = 1 To RowsCount
        dCol = 0
        IsNotSameColumn = False
        For sCol = 1 To ColumnsCount
            If Len(CStr(Data(Row, sCol))) > 0 Then
                dCol = dCol + 1
                If Not IsNotSameColumn Then
                    If dCol < sCol Then IsNotSameColumn = True
                End If
                If IsNotSameColumn Then
                    Data(Row, dCol) = Data(Row, sCol)
                    Data(Row, sCol) = Empty
                End If
            End If
        Next sCol
    Next Row
    
    rg.Value = Data

End Sub

